# How to insert the data into the database according to the radio option value in PHP?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a form, with two options buyer and seller.
If the user is a buyer then the email id should enter and if the user is a seller then the mobile number should enter.

```js
checkAccount_type(); // onload 
$('input[name="account_type"]').click(function() {
  checkAccount_type();
});

function checkAccount_type() {
  if ($('#acc_seller').is(':checked')) {
    $('.show_mobilefield').show();
    $('.show_emailfield').hide();
  } else {
    $('.show_emailfield').show();
    $('.show_mobilefield').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<main class="site-main">
  <div class="entry-content signup">
    <div class="">
      <form action="controller/access_control" name="signup_form" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="signup_inner">
          <div class="form-group d-flex">

            <div class="">
              <label class="container">
              <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_seller" checked="checked">
              <span class="checkmark"></span> I am a Seller
            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="">
              <label class="container">
              <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_buyer">
              <span class="checkmark"></span> I am a buyer
        </label>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group show_mobilefield">
            <label>Mobile no</label>
            <input type="text" name="mobileno" class="form-control" placeholder="enter mobile no">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group show_emailfield">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="enter email id">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="enter password here">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="enter password here">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mt-2">
            <input type="submit" name="signup" class="" value="Signup">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="singup">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am using below logic:

```
$account_type=sanitize_data($_POST['account_type']);
$password=$_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword=$_POST['confirmpassword'];

if (empty($account_type)) {
      $errorMsg[]=  "Please select account type";
}
elseif(empty($password)){
 $errorMsg[] = 'Please enter password';
  }

elseif($password!==$confirmpassword){
$errorMsg[] = 'Password didnot matched with confirm password';
}

else{
try {
  if ($account_type==1) {
    $mobileno=sanitize_data($_POST['mobileno']);
  }
  else{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
  }

 $newpassword=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 12]);

  
    $data=array(
      'email' => $email,
      'mobileno'=>$mobileno,
      'password' => $newpassword,
      'account_type' => $account_type, 
  );

$sql="INSERT INTO `tbl_register`(`email`, `mobileno`, `password`, `account_type`) VALUES (:email,:mobileno, :password, :account_type)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);     
//$response['error'] = "true";

header("Location:list.php");

  } catch (Exception $e) {
      $dbh->rollback(); 
      print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
    
  }
}

function sanitize_data($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;    
}
```

I have an issue with the `else part (try and insert query)`. I mean, If I enter the mobile number then I am getting the issue an email and if I enter email id then I am getting the issue on mobile.

I know I added the POST value  `email` and `mobile` in the array and in the `insert query`.

Errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: email in
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: mobileno in

Do I need to use some if condition?

Answer (score 0):

If email or mobile any one required at a time, then you can modify code as below :

```
$data=array(
      'email' => $email ?? null,
      'mobileno'=>$mobileno ?? null,
      'password' => $newpassword,
      'account_type' => $account_type, 
  );
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting error Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null

Comment: try replacing null with two single quotes

Comment: @AaronHenderson, Yes, I added like  'email' => $email ?? "", and it's working.